# PySimpleGUI freezing due to background tasks using Jpype and cant use multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pysimplegui, jpype, ema-workbench

I am currently developing a GUI in python with the PySimpleGUI library. The idea is to allow users to run NetLogo models by interacting with the GUI. The back-end for this uses EMA workbench (https://emaworkbench.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run the models.

The main problem I have at the moment is that the GUI freezes when the experiments are ran due to the program running on a singele thread and thus interrupting the window.read() loop to run the GUI. After the experiments are done, the loop continues and the GUI works fine again, but this does result in the window not responding during the experiments.

Normally, this would be easy to fix by using a separate thread to run either the GUI or the back-end, while the main thread continues with the other part.

However, because PySimpleGUI is built on top of tkinter, multithreading is not supported and attempting to put the window.read() loop in a thread results in an error. This can easily be demonstrated with the following code snippet, quickly made so dont mind the bad programming syntax (Here the time.sleep() can be seen as the run of the experiments):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import threading

layout = [[sg.Button("Freeze!", key='freeze')]]
window = sg.Window('Test window', layout)
done = False

# Define a function that continues reading the window in a thread
def continue_reading():
    global window
    global done
    while not done:
        event, values = window.read()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'freeze':

        # Create the thread to continue the reading of the window
        t = threading.Thread(target=continue_reading)
        t.start()

        # Emulate the running of experiments with time.sleep()
        time.sleep(10)
        done = True

window.close()
```

> RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different apartment

Because EMA workbench is built on top of PyNetLogo, which in turn is built on top of Jpype, the experiment running also can't be done on a thread because jpype.shutdownJVM() must be called from the main thread, resulting in the error:

> RuntimeError: Shutdown must be called from main thread

**Question:** Does anyone have an idea how to work around either of these two errors to allow the GUI to remain responsive while running the experiments? The GUI only needs to display a text box while the experiments are running, so all I need is for it to stay responsive, nothing fancy.

Comment: A short and compete script to show your issue is preferred.

Comment: @JasonYang I have added a script to show the error with threading in PySimpleGUI

Comment: "your GUI must never run as anything but the main program thread and no threads can directly call PySimpleGUI calls."  Maybe you can refer demo code here, https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Multithreaded_Long_Tasks.py